# How to deal with an existing Aurora MySQL database and serverless functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-rds, serverless, vercel

I am stuck in my current situation: I have a regular Aurora MySQL RDS cluster and some apps that make use of it (some query the database constantly), now I also have a Next.js application hosted on Vercel, this moment I realised I cannot connect to the database in my serverless functions.

How can I deal with this situation? I figured one easy way would be to migrate to Aurora serverless but I think that will be expensive because of the apps that constantly query the database (both the serverless function and apps should access the same data)

Comment: How would migrating to Aurora serverless help you connect to the database from Vercel? The Database would still be running in an AWS VPC, and still be inaccessible from outside AWS. Your problem is that you need to access a database running in one cloud service from your application code running in another cloud service. The only option you really have here is to make the database publicly accessible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I still have to think about that but surely this can't be the recommended solution? I think serverless databases have some sort of extra protection to allow outside access, can I open the database in a secure way without serverless?

Comment: Actually the opposite is true, serverless Aurora databases don't allow outside access at all.  It isn't possible to enable the Publicly Accessible flag on Aurora serverless databases. According to [the Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/solutions/databases) you will need to make the DB public and only rely on username/password for your security.

Comment: Thanks for that link, looks like it is indeed the solution, the only issue I may have now is that there isn't a straightforward alternative to pgBouncer..

Comment: I just thought of another option. You could switch to Aurora Serverless and then use the [Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html). That should be accessible from outside the VPC. You would then use AWS IAM access keys inside your serverless code to access the database.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?